# Javascript - error when a script tag in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a page with the following code:

```
<script>
window.str = '<script></script>';
</script>
```

This results in an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

What's going on? Entering the same code into the console runs without issue. [Here is a jsbin demonstrating the issue](http://jsbin.com/sozej/1/edit?html,console,output)

Comment: And some of those: [`[javascript] "</script>"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+%22%3C%2Fscript%3E%22)

Comment: The `</script>` tag inside the string closes the first `<script>` tag, leaving you with invalid JavaScript. HTML doesn't know about JavaScript, it only sees the closing tag. It works in the console because the code is not in a HTML context.

Comment: Oh good find @FelixKling that was it. Wow, I don't think I've learned something new about javascript in months if not years.

Comment: :) It's more an HTML issue than a JS issue, I'd say, but it's nice to learn something new :)

Comment: Hmm, whats the correct thing to do here? Should I delete the question or leave it up but vote to close as dupelicate?

Comment: I'd let it close as duplicate... I wished I found a better one though. This has been asked a couple of times for sure.

Comment: if you think it's beneficial, vote to close as dupe, otherwise delete. Or ask on meta :)

Comment: Yeah, I'll leave it up and vote to close - I asked in a different way than the dupe OP.

Answer (score 3):

the error went away when I escaped the `/` with a `\`.

http://jsbin.com/xugabolu/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

The hackish work-around for this is something like:

```
<script>
window.str = '<scr' + 'ipt></scri' + 'pt>';
</script>
```

In this way, you wind up with the string you want without confusing the parser.

Or, insert it as a DOM element if that is the ultimate goal.